# align images next to brand in Bootstrap Nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is position an rss image and twitter image right next to the brand and within the inner nav.  This is how I would like it to look:

This is a JSFiddle of how it actually looks:
http://jsfiddle.net/taxman10m/bsQB3/2/

This is how I would like it to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWrj3.jpg

Below is my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a href="" class="brand">Blog Name</a>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="rss.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="twitter.png" /></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu Item 2</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        </ul>
      </div> 

    </div>

  </nav>
```

Any suggestions?  I tried various different things (taking it out of the `<ul>`, wrapping it in a div, using various classes) and nothing worked, so I'm stumped as what to do next.

Comment: add it to jsfiddle that the people can help you.

Comment: From the images, it appears that you are looking for better spacing between the images. Is that the case?

Comment: They look better close together IMHO

Comment: Yes, the images should be closer together and they should both be closer to the brand.

Comment: Here is a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taxman10m/bsQB3/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in line 658 at **bootstrap.min.css**  change the **value of padding** to be like this:

```
.navbar .nav>li>a {
  padding: 10px 5px 10px;
  }
```

also if you want the space between them less than this **change the value of (5)** to a smaller number.

hope this solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it pretty much does.  That's a lot! However it applies that padding to all menu items.  How can I style that padding to apply only to the those 2 images?

Comment: to do this you will need to change the <ul class="nav"> to another name like <ul class="social">, then target it. after that you need to target the link inside this new class.

it was not good from the start to use class with name ="nav" inside the navbar because you have a <ul class="nav"> under it with its css attributes. "which we changed now"